# Why echo \"$(hostname -I)\" shows a space after last number? How to avoid this?

Tags: bash, shell-script

`echo \"$(hostname -I)\"` outputs `"111.111.111 "`
How can I avoid the extra space and have instead `"111.111.111"`

Comment: because: `hostname -I` writes this space

Comment: You can use `sed` to remove the space: `echo \"$(hostname -I | sed 's/ $//')\"`

Comment: @larsks i like your answer...if you put it in answers, i will choose it as the right one

Comment: I think @ikkachu's answer using bash parameter expansion is probably a better option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the command prints a space, it'll be included in the output. Well, actually, since the command substitution is not quoted, the result will be word-split, and the two strings `"111.111.111` and `"` will be passed to `echo` as two distinct arguments, which `echo` then prints joined with a single space. It doesn't change output here with `echo`, but in many other cases it would matter. If there was nothing after the command substitution, the space would disappear during word splitting.

It's likely that `hostname -I` prints a trailing space since it may print multiple IP addresses, and it's simpler to print a space after each one, instead of skipping it for the last one.

To remove the space, you could use the suffix-removal expansion:

```
ip="$(hostname -I)"
ip="${ip% }"
printf '"%s"\n' "$ip"
```

or utilize word splitting in your favor:

```
printf '"%s"\n' $(hostname -I)
```

The latter would quote each space-separated IP address individually and print them one per line.